# Combining MultipleObjectMixin and FormView

Tags: django

I'm using a class based view in Django that inherits from both `MultipleObjectMixin` and `FormView`. The code is like so:

```
class UnseenActivityView(MultipleObjectMixin, FormView):
    form_class = UnseenActivityForm
    template_name = "user_unseen_activity.html"
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = #some queryset       
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UnseenActivityView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context["verified"] = VERIFIED_USERS #this is a list of special IDs 
        return context
```

This piece of code returns me a `keyerror` for `u'object_list'`. It seems `object_list` is not present in the kwargs dictionary. Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue? I needed a `FormView` for my cbv, but one that was paginated, hence combined it with a `MultipleObjectMixin`.

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 86, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 155, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
  File "/home/hassan/Desktop/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 5494, in get_context_data
    context = super(UnseenActivityView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 95, in get_context_data
    queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list')
KeyError: u'object_list'
```

Comment: Please post the traceback if you want help debugging.

Comment: @Alasdair: added the traceback. solarissmoke gives a good reason for the dead-end I've run into. I'd probably need to implement pagination with a Formview myself. If there's anything you can add in that regard, feel free to do so as an answer.

Comment: You're using a very old version of Django there - Django 1.6+ uses `kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)` instead. I agree with the hint from the Django docs that @solarissmoke quoted. I think you're expecting generic views to do too much. Try using the [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/) class in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to run into problems with this approach.

Python uses a [method resolution order](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) to determine which method on the parent class(es) gets called. In your case, `super(UnseenActivityView, self).get_context_data()` will call `MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data` but not `FormView.get_context_data`. Either way you will not end up with the context from both parent classes being passed to your template, and something will break.

This is also the reason you are getting the `KeyError` - `MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data` expects an `object_list` kwarg, but isn't supplied one, because the `get()` method that normally calls `get_context_data()` is coming from the `FormView` (method resolution again), which has no knowledge of any `object_list`.

I would suggest that rather to combine these classes in this way you heed the [advice in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#extending-generic-views):

> Generic views will have a limit. If you find you’re struggling to implement your view as a subclass of a generic view, then you may find it more effective to write just the code you need, using your own class-based or functional views.

In this case I'd suggest you use the `FormView` to handle your form, but write the code for handling a list view yourself rather than trying to plug in the `MultipleObjectMixin`. You can of course copy the logic from `MultipleObjectMixin`.

Comment: Yea you're right. I actually wanted to use pagination, which is what got me into this in the first place.